# What does Drow Speech sound like?

Tags: forgotten-realms, languages

I am about to play a Drow Rogue-Fighter and I want to roleplay my character well, and this includes doing a voice. What is the proper voice for a [charismatic] Drow [Rogue-Fighter]? I was thinking something kind of low and blunt, but wanted to know if there are any canonical audio or descriptive references available.

Comment: Answers to this question should be **backed up with canonical sources.** This question is not asking about personal opinion absent citations.

Comment: Answers that are just opinion not referencing canon have been deleted.  If you edit your answer to include sources feel free and flag it for undeletion.

Answer (score 24):

The closest thing to an official sound for the drow language might come from TSR's *The Drow of the Underdark* (1991), which describes [some drow vocabulary and phrases](http://www.angelfire.com/mi/OtherPage/DrowLanguage.html). The book describes drow speech as follows:

> Drow are as eloquent and musical in their speech as other elves, and are capable of readily reproducing the sounds of other languages. Most drow are good mimics; a drow overhearing speech who imitates the words and tone is 45% likely (+1% per exposure to the language) to be audibly mistaken for the being they are imitating.

According to this, drow sound like elves, and drow adventurers are likely to speak with little or no accent. You can find several elvish language references on Youtube, including J.R.R Tolkien reading a poem in Elvish. Legolas from the Lord of the Rings movies is another good example, although a drow's cultural background would lend itself to a slightly more violent and selfish tone.

Answer (score 11):

Search for sound clips from Icewind Dale 2, there's 2 drow clips for each gender if memory serves and are really good if that's what you're looking for.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p651lYmaUkY, not the exact clip (it's someone imitating the voice clip) but very close, still looking for the original one (my IWD2 CD is broke and I can't reinstall it).

Comment: Zanath, perhaps you can link them for us?

Comment: That voice clip is in Polish, not Elvish :)

Answer (score 7):

This may be not be exactly what you want, but many of the Forgotten Realms books by RA Salvatore have audio-book versions available.  I think there are relatively few actual drow words in there, but you have, often rather good, voice actors taking pains to voice a drow and to give different voices/accents to different characters as they read.

Plus, they are rather entertaining on their own and worth listening to on commutes.